# Running many CLI processes from Python, avoid CPU overload

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm creating a python script to launch many processes via the CLI. Once process per file found in a certain directory. And then I just loop over the files and launch the process which works on that file.

```
for path in pathlist:
    # Prepare cli call
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd...)
    processes.append(p)
```

I'm also adding all processes to a list to wait for them at the end of the script. Since there can be 100s of files I don't want to overload the CPU and make things slower due to too many context switches. Plus at some point memory will also become a limiting factor.

How can I control in above "logic" to not "flood" the cpu/OS and slow things down?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the higher level interface provided by [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), which provides an `Executor` class is parametrized by the maximum number of workers you want. It handles the logic of managing these workers.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import subprocess

MAX_WORKERS = 5

def worker(i):
    with subprocess.Popen(f"sleep 3 && echo {i}", shell=True) as p:
        """Do some stuff if you want with the Popen object"""
        """ It will wait for the subprocess to terminate"""
        """ before exiting the with block"""

        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
    futures = []
    for i in range(25):
        futures.append(executor.submit(worker, i=i))
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

print("ALL FINISHED")
```

Note, I wrapped the call to `Popen` in a function that uses a context manager (`with` statement) to invoke it because by default it is non-bocking. You are going to want to wait for the processes to finish. I don't know why you are using `subprocess.Popen`, so I kept it in case you really need it, but generally, you should stick to `subprocess.run` for most straightforward cases. It blocks untils the command finishes by default. In that case, you could simplify it to:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import subprocess
        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = []
    for i in range(25):
        future = executor.submit(
            subprocess.run, 
            args=f"sleep 3 && echo {i}",
            shell=True
        )
        futures.append(future)
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

print("ALL FINISHED")
```

Note, I am using `concurrent.futures.wait` which will wait until all futures have completed.

For your case, I think you are going to have something like:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import subprocess

N_WORKERS = 5

files = get_files_somehow()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N_WORKERS) as executor:
    futures = []
    for path in files:
        future = executor.submit(
            subprocess.run, 
            args=["foo", file],
        )
        futures.append(future)
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

print("ALL FINISHED")
```

Play around with the `N_WORKERS` to find a suitable value for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this possible solution, good enough for the script I'm making:

```
processes = []
for path in pathlist:
    # Prepare cli call
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd...)
    processes.append(p)
    
    if len(processes) >= 8:         
        processes[0].wait() 
        del processes[0] 

for proc in processes:
    proc.wait()
```

if the limit is reached I wait for the "oldest" process that was submitted and then remove it from the list, only then will the next one be submitted, at the end I wait for the remaining ones of them to complete.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code:

```py
# Set a limit for the number of concurrent processes
max_processes = 10

# Initialize a counter for running processes
current_processes = 0

for path in pathlist:
    # Check if the maximum number of processes is reached
    while current_processes >= max_processes:
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for a while before checking again

    # Prepare cli call
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd...)
    processes.append(p)
    current_processes += 1

# Wait for all processes to finish
for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

Comment: I don't see any code that would decrease the `current_processes` variable? Your code will go in an infinite loop in case `current_processes >= max_processes` is ever `True`